# How to make Document Icon clickable in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

Clicking the icon in Type column is highlighting the item instead of launching the document. I implemented the solution from the following blog
http://blog.cube4.com.au/?p=1006.

Sometimes it works fine but sometimes it is not.Could you suggest me how to resolve this issue.

Comment: could you please tell us what you mean by sometime its work and sometime not? their are limitation in that workaround.

Comment: Jave script worked perfectly fine for few times and I was able to launch the document by clicking the icon.Now it stopped woking not able to launch the document.Could you tell me what are the limitations in that workaround.